# pandas pivot table on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

**INPUT TABLE**

| pcd | INCOME | Education | age1to_20 | TG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1001 | INCOME_1 | Education_1 | 1 | 1 |
| a1003 | INCOME_2 | Education_2 | 0 | 2 |
| a1001 | INCOME_3 | Education_2 | 5 | 2 |
| a1002 | INCOME_2 | Education_2 | 1 | 5 |
| a1003 | INCOME_1 | Education_2 | 3 | 4 |

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

| pcd | INCOME_1 | INCOME_2 | INCOME_3 | Education_1 | Education_2 | age1to_20 | TG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1001 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 1.5 |
| a1002 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| a1003 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

***pcd is index and income1,income2,income3,education1,education2,age are aggregated to sum while TG is aggregated to average.***

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['pcd', 'age1to_20'],
           aggfunc={'INCOME':sum,'Education'=sum,'age1to_20'=sum,'TG':avg},fill_value=0)
```

Tried above code but finding no success

Answer (score 2):

You can first [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to reshape, and finally [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to combine the 'pcd':

```
agg_funcs = {'TG': 'mean', 'pcd': 'first'}

out = (df
   .melt(['pcd', 'age1to_20', 'TG'])
   .assign(v=1)
   .pivot_table(index=['pcd', 'age1to_20', 'TG'], columns='value',
                values='v', fill_value=0)
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.groupby('pcd', as_index=False)
                    .agg({c: agg_funcs.get(c, 'sum') for c in d.columns}))
)
```

Output:

```
     pcd  age1to_20   TG  Education_1  Education_2  INCOME_1  INCOME_2  INCOME_3
0  a1001          6  1.5            1            1         1         0         1
1  a1002          1  5.0            0            1         0         1         0
2  a1003          3  3.0            0            2         1         1         0
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use crosstab and groupby:

```
x=pd.crosstab(df['pcd'],columns=df['INCOME'])
print(x)
'''
INCOME  INCOME_1  INCOME_2  INCOME_3
pcd                                 
a1001          1         0         1
a1002          0         1         0
a1003          1         1         0
'''

y=pd.crosstab([df['pcd']],columns=[df['Education']])
z=df.groupby('pcd').agg({'age1to_20':'sum','TG':'mean'})
final=x.join([y,z])
print(final)
'''
       INCOME_1  INCOME_2  INCOME_3  Education_1  Education_2  age1to_20   TG
pcd                                                                          
a1001         1         0         1            1            1          6  1.5
a1002         0         1         0            0            1          1  5.0
a1003         1         1         0            0            2          3  3.0
'''
```

Comment: what if I want one of the crosstab column to be mean over sum.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify where the values are going to come from and which columns will specify your new column names.

Also, it's not very clear to me where your values are coming from.

But it would look like something like this, e.g.,

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['pcd', 'age1to_20'], 
           values=['age1to_20']
           columns=['income', 'education']
           aggfunc={'INCOME':sum,'TG':avg},fill_value=0)
```